# Is it possible to derive(fake) a location path to an in-memory MemoryStream file?

Tags: c#, file-io, .net-3.5, filestream, memorystream

Is it possible to derive a location path of an in-memory file?

My justification for doing this is based on having a collection of images that are retrieved by my WinForms application in a Base64 encoded string format. I need to build up some HTML and inject these images so that they can be rendered on an embedded page in a WebBrowser control on my application. Since we're talking about HTML here, I need to use the `<IMG>` tag to display the image.  This element needs to accept a "src" path which means I need to determine a method of deriving an absolute/relative path to each of the in-memory images.

Comment: A `MemoryStream` does not pretend to be a file... nor do many other stream types. Some *readers* might expose a logical path... can you be more specific about the scenario here where a path is being queried?

Comment: Perhaps it would be more helpful if you mention your goal. Why do you want to do it? There could be a much simpler answer than trying to fake stuff.

Comment: Likely, he is using a third party library which expects a filePath as an argument but he has the file only in memory and does not want to write it on a temp path

Comment: I've re-factored the question above to include my goal.

Comment: for small images, you can use `data:` urls.

Comment: My images are > 32KB so embedded data will not work. See: http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/embedding-images-in-html-using-c/

Answer (score 2):

If you control the application running on the server (which you indicated in a comment), then you should be able to redirect requests for particular resources. For example, if the user application requests "http://myserver/memory/imgxxx.jpg", the server should be able to intercept that and, rather than try to serve imgxxx.jpg from disk, construct an image from the data in memory, and ship it down to the client.

Now, if you're just shipping the base64 encoded data to the client, and want the client to somehow access the data and do the conversion ... that's a harder problem. I can envision doing something with JavaScript to replace all of the img tags that have some given attributes with the corresponding image. But I suspect that'd get pretty messy. If it's even possible.

Another possibility is to create a derived `WebBrowser` component and customize its behavior. A good example is in the [CreateSink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.createsink.aspx) method documentation. It might be possible to write a handler that is called whenever the component wants to download something. You could then intercept the call and supply your in-memory image. I'm not certain that this is possible. You might take a look at [WebBrowser customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I will say, though, that it's probably easier to just write the files and use a "file://" url.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately my problem is the latter - "shipping the base64 encoded data to the client, and want the client to somehow access the data and do the conversion"

Comment: Here is a relevant post on your first suggestion: http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/serving-images-using-httplistener-414552.html

Answer (score 1):

You can build a light weight HTTP server into your application by using the [`HttpListener class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx).

You will want to use the asynchronous model. Create a url that it serves content to, such as "http://*:8080/appdata", and then use that url within your html (http://localhost:8080/appdata/someinmemoryresource").

When theHttpListener receives a request, look at the path and respond with whatever in memory data it is you want to serve!

Answer (score 0):

The `IMG` tag does not need a path, it needs a URL. You cannot reference in-memory data with a URL. The browser is going to issue a second HTTP request with the URL provided in the `IMG` tag and that URL must be valid at this point.

Consider adding an MVC action or an HTTP handler to return the image bytes. Or save it to disk.

Comment: It is possible to have a local path location e.g. src="c:/files/abc.jpg". This is what I mean by Path. It's looking like I need to save to disk :-(

Comment: No that is not possible because this path is not a valid URL from the clients point of view. The client cannot access the hard disk of the server (for obvious reasons).

Comment: I just applied a quick test and I confirm that the image gets displayed using src="file:///C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/imgtest.jpg". Note, I'm displaying the image in a WinForms WebBrowser application.

Comment: File URLs always reference the machine the browser is running on. It works by accident right now -  your server and client are on the same machine ;-) How would you expect web security to work if you could access any file on any server on the web?

Comment: Actually I applaud you for testing your theory. Look at how the web is built: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol That will provide you some nice insights.

Comment: But the server and client are on the same machine. Remember that this is a WebForms Application with a WebBrowser control. I have the binary image in-memory which I need to display on this browser. Surely, if I take this binary image and save it locally(say isolated storage) then I will be able to access and load the image by referencing it in the src like I describe above?

Comment: I understand. Yes, if both are on the same machine that will work. You probably cannot make the in-memory images available to the WebBrowser control but you can save them to disk (or use an HTTP-based solution if you don't want temp files!).